# android emulator controls misplaced

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

Is android emulator always right? I mean in xml(It shows the device as Nexus One) I am placing the elements properly but when it runs on emulator (Nexus One) it is misplaced. I do not have a real device of similar size as Nexus one otherwise I would have checked.

Kindly advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use width and height in pixels. use `weight` and `weightsum` and also use "`match_parent`" ,"`fill_parent`" & "`wrap content`" to place your tools and give dimensions in "`dp`". i think this might be helpful to you.